# Java Hibernate error : could not resolve property: cart_id of: pojos.Cart

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I got this `could not resolve property: cart_id of: pojos.Cart` exception when i'm running my project. I'm using hibernate in Netbeans. I removed and re-added hibernate couple of times using Netbeans wizard, but not worked. How can i solve this ? Thank you.

Here is my mapping file,

Cart.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="pojos.Cart" table="cart" catalog="design">
    <id name="cartId" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="cart_id" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="date" type="string">
        <column name="date" length="10" />
    </property>
    <property name="total" type="java.lang.Double">
        <column name="total" precision="22" scale="0" />
    </property>
    <set name="userses" table="users" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="cart_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="pojos.Users" />
    </set>
    <set name="cartRegisters" table="cart_register" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="cart_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="pojos.CartRegister" />
    </set>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Edit**

Cart.java

```
    package pojos;
// Generated Nov 25, 2016 6:08:52 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.6.0

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Cart implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer cartId;
    private String date;
    private Double total;
    private Set userses = new HashSet(0);
    private Set cartRegisters = new HashSet(0);

    public Cart() {
    }

    public Cart(String date, Double total, Set userses, Set cartRegisters) {
        this.date = date;
        this.total = total;
        this.userses = userses;
        this.cartRegisters = cartRegisters;
    }

    public Integer getCartId() {
        return this.cartId;
    }

    public void setCartId(Integer cartId) {
        this.cartId = cartId;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return this.date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Double getTotal() {
        return this.total;
    }

    public void setTotal(Double total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public Set getUserses() {
        return this.userses;
    }

    public void setUserses(Set userses) {
        this.userses = userses;
    }

    public Set getCartRegisters() {
        return this.cartRegisters;
    }

    public void setCartRegisters(Set cartRegisters) {
        this.cartRegisters = cartRegisters;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide the class pojos.Cart as well?

Comment: @simas_ch: I posted pojos:Cart

Comment: hmm. could provide the whole project? Maybe on github?

Comment: Just read the error message. It says "could not resolve property: cart_id of: pojos.Cart". So, look at the class `pojos.Cart`. Now try to find a property in that class named `cart_id`. Can you find one? I can't. I can only find something vaguely similar: `cartId`.

Comment: @JBNizet: Thank you. I changed `cartId` to `cart_id`, but still same error. :-(

Comment: You should do the opposite. Respect the Java naming conventions. Look for incorrect usage of cart_id in the other xml files (And seriously consider using standard JPA annotations instead of XML files. We're not in 2002 anymore).

Comment: `cartId` id the id name. So should i edit it, because other java files, using id name are not throw exceptions.

Comment: @simas_ch: I uploaded whole project : [Full project](https://github.com/MalindaWMD/design/blob/master/DesignBucket.rar)

Answer (score 0):

It's not the mapping. It's a query in cartModal method getMaxCart():

```
 cr.setProjection(Projections.max("cart_id"));
```

Comment: Yeah, but what is wrong in this code. I used this method in other files and it's working ?

Comment: It should be cartId